# Asterisk: Adding agents to queues

Tags: asterisk

I'm trying to add agents to queues in realtime, by adding them to the `queue_members` table, the old syntax for adding them is using Agent/1001 but the `chan_agents` along with the Agent channel have been removed from the recent versions, and the current presented syntax is this

```
member => Local/1001@agents,0,May Flowers,Agent:1001
member => Local/1002@agents,0,John Doe,Agent:1002
```

which translate to

> queue_name : agents_queue
>
> interface : Local/1001@agents
>
> state_interface : Agent:1001

but both of them gives me this error

> NOTICE[18541][C-0000000a]: core_local.c:701 local_call: No such
>   extension/context 1001@agents while calling Local channel

EDIT: agent was already added in `agents.conf`

```
[1001]
fullname=Will Meadows
```

EDIT 2:
using an agents context

```
[agents]
exten=> _*,n,AgentRequest(first_agent)
```

there is no error using a context but the agent is still shown as Invalid

> May Flowers (Local/first_agent@myagents from  Agent:first_agent)
>   (ringinuse enabled) (Invalid) has taken no calls yet

my goal is to give the agents the ability to login using `AgentLogin` and routing calls to them through a queue.

Comment: Can you please post the dialplan context for `[Agents]`?  `chan_local` is trying to find *"extension 1001 in context agents"* , and the error is claiming it can't.

Comment: the problem is that i cant find any docs on how to manage agents context aside from this https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Controlling+the+way+Queues+Call+Agents but it is using eal and cant use it from ```queue_members``` in realtime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error in your `[agents]` context:

```
[agents]
exten=> _*,n,AgentRequest(first_agent)
```

should be

```
[agents]
exten => _*,1,AgentRequest(first_agent)
 same => n, Verbose(2,AgentRequest Status: ${AGENT_STATUS})
```

... note the "priority" item is "1" not "n". Change that and let me know if things start working.

The second line will be useful for further debugging if this doesn't fix your problem, or if the problem "progresses".

Answer (score -1):

you have to add agents in agents.conf file first...

Comment: im not sure why you need to use Local/XXXX@agents, but in you example you must create [agents] context in extensions.conf.

Comment: Thats what was provided in the ```queues.conf``` file, what is the syntax for agents context?